# Pausing video after hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code to make a video play on hover, but i need it to stop playing when not hovering. What do I need to add to the JS to make this work?

```
<div class="padding-box height-40">
                <div>
                    <div class="media_link_overlay" id="video-home"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="background">
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="text">
                            <video id="video-hover" width="100%" height="100%" preload="auto" onMouseover="mouseoversound.playclip()">
                                 <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/videos/homepage_thx.mp4';?>" />
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>      

<script>
$("#video-home").hover(function(){
    $("#video-home")[0].play();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method has two handler functions, one is `handlerIn` and other is `handlerOut`. Currently, you are only using the first handler. You can use both and make video `play` on hover-in and `pause` on hover-out like:

```
$("#video-home").hover(
  function() {
    $("#video-home")[0].play();
  },
  function() {
    $("#video-home")[0].pause();
  }
);
```

If you want to completely stop the video and make it start from the beginning on next hover-in, you can use:

```
$("#video-home").hover(
  function() {
    $("#video-home")[0].play();
  },
  function() {
    $("#video-home")[0].pause();
    $("#video-home")[0].currentTime = 0;
  }
);
```